# flexbox - center items for 1/3 and 2/3 proportion

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to center item (one) in 1/3 row space and center another item (two) in the rest of the row space (2/3).

https://jsfiddle.net/gpe9a5qb/1/

How to center items to the specific space they fit so they will NOT center depends on their size but depend on the size of the space they are signed (1/3 and 2/3)?

```css
body {
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: brown;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.one {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="one">1/3</div>
    <div class="two">2/3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.one should be center inside 1/3 and .two must be center inside 2/3 space.

Comment: what is wrong with this solution? https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/issues/2411

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I get this correctly, you are speaking about center horizontally.

The css will look like this

```css
body {
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: brown;
}

.container {
  background:red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
}

.box > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 33.33%; 
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  flex-basis: 66.66%;
}
```

What I did here, is that I put flex on the inner divs, and center their content (not the parent container, which you can't be centered, because they take up the space).

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. Just one modification needed:

*Make each flex item a flex container with `justify-content: center`.*

That's it.

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: space-around */ /* remove; doing nothing */
}

.one {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 1 auto;

  /* NEW */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  
  /* NEW */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="one">1/3</div>
    <div class="two">2/3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want both your `.one` and `.two` elements to be vertically centered inside of `.box`, whilst still taking up one-third and two-thirds of the space respectively.

In order to achieve this, you simply need to ensure that `.box` takes up the full `height` of `.container`.

You can achieve this by either setting `display: flex` on `.container` along with `flex: 1` on `.box`:

```css
body {
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: brown;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 1;
}

.one {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="one">1/3</div>
    <div class="two">2/3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or simply by setting `height: 100%` on `.box`:

```css
body {
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: brown;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
}

.one {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="one">1/3</div>
    <div class="two">2/3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nicely explained but I need text in .one and .two to be center. Sorry if it wasn't obvious. BTW how do you add code snippet here?